# How to configure hp Deskject Ink Advantage printer 3777

Tags: 16.04, printing

I am having a hp Deskjet Ink Advantage 3777 printer. I tried all the way to install the printer with my system but i failed.
So kindly provide some valuable suggestion.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 03f0:0653 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 05c6:f00e Qualcomm, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I installed printer via printer software provided default with ubuntu 16.04 however i cant able to take print out

A detailed output of `hp-check -t` is in
[hplip](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/453904)

Comment: You need to install `hplip`.

Comment: hplip is already installed, by my printer is not listed in it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install **HPLIP Binary Plug-In**

Some HP printers require proprietary software technologies to allow full access to printer features and performance.  Unfortunately, these technologies cannot be open sourced, but to resolve this HP uses a binary plug-in for these printers.  This plug-in works in conjunction with our Linux Open Source Printing Software to improve the printing experience for HP’s Linux Printing Customers.

As of February 2009 (concurrent with the 3.9.2 release of HPLIP), there were aproximately 50 LaserJet printers or MFP's that either require the plug-in for the device to operate or use the plug-in for enhanced performance (i.e. improved print quality, faster print speed, etc.).  However, additional devices (including inkjet products) are anticipated to use the plug-in in the future.  For the current list of plug-in enabled printers see [this link](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/plugin.html), which also includes the device features that are enabled or enhanced by the plug-in.

Most Linux distributions include HPLIP with their software, but most do not include the plug-in.  Therefore, it is a safe practice to run a utility called "hp-setup", which, will install the printer into the CUPS spooler, download, and install the plug-in at the appropriate time.

To install the plug-in using the GUI you can follow these procedures:

1. [Launch a command-line window](http://hplipopensource.com/node/307) and enter:

   hp-setup
2. Select your connection type and click "Next".
3. Select your printer from "Selected Devices" list and click "Next".
4. Enter your root password when prompted and click "Next".
5. Use the recommended installation method and click "Next".
6. Check the box to accept with the "Driver Plug-In License Agreement" and click "Next".
7. Finish the installation of the printer as normal, however you may be prompted to re-enter your user name and password.

If you run into any additional install problems you can go to our [known issues](http://hplipopensource.com/node/311) page and check for a solution.

For advanced users who wish to install HPLIP components manually, a utility exists (hp-plugin) which will download and install the plugin file, but it does not also install a printer queue like hp-setup does.

Do the following:

1. [Launch a command-line window](http://hplipopensource.com/node/307) and enter:

   hp-plugin
2. Follow the directions above for navigating the GUI but remember that the printer que will not be installed through this process.

I hope this information helps.